# Union of infinitely many recursive sets that is not recursive but recursively enumerable?

Tags: computability

I am looking for an example such that the union of infinitely many recursive sets is not recursive but recursively enumerable.

I was thinking taking $S_i=\{i\}$ and then taking the union of these with the indexes in the halting set, so that the union is the halting set, which is not recursive, but recursively enumerable.

However, I am not sure this is the union of *infinitely* many sets, is the halting set infinite?

Comment: Every finite set is recursive.

Comment: Thank you, everything makes so much more sense now!